# pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None] in Django-Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I installed Django-Celery in my server and trying to send a task by following code:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from OJ.models import *

In [2]: from OJ.tasks import *

In [3]: r=judge_delay.delay(Submit.objects.filter(id=9912)[0])
```

But I got the results as

```
$ ./manage.py celeryd -l debug
[2017-04-26 19:46:46,961: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Preparing bootsteps.
[2017-04-26 19:46:46,963: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Building graph...
[2017-04-26 19:46:46,963: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: New boot order: {Timer, Hub, Queues (intra), Pool, Autoreloader, StateDB, Beat, Autoscaler, Consumer}
[2017-04-26 19:46:46,967: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Preparing bootsteps.
[2017-04-26 19:46:46,968: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Building graph...
[2017-04-26 19:46:46,970: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: New boot order: {Connection, Events, Mingle, Tasks, Control, Gossip, Heart, Agent, event loop}

 -------------- celery@OJ v3.1.25 (Cipater)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.19.0-33-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         default:0x7f87e70e6a90 (djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader)
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     amqp://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- 
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . OJ.tasks.judge_delay
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap

[2017-04-26 19:46:46,975: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Hub
[2017-04-26 19:46:46,975: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2017-04-26 19:46:46,975: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
[2017-04-26 19:46:47,077: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2017-04-26 19:46:47,078: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
[2017-04-26 19:46:47,078: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
[2017-04-26 19:46:47,090: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2017-04-26 19:46:47,091: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2017-04-26 19:46:47,091: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Events
[2017-04-26 19:46:47,101: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2017-04-26 19:46:47,101: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Mingle
[2017-04-26 19:46:47,101: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,114: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,114: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,115: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Tasks
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,124: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,124: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Control
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,131: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,131: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Gossip
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,138: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,138: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Heart
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,140: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,140: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting event loop
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,143: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@OJ ready.
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,143: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Hub.register Pool...
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,144: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->16
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,194: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-04-26 19:46:48,194: INFO/MainProcess] Events of group {task} enabled by remote.
[2017-04-26 19:46:53,196: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-04-26 19:46:58,194: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-04-26 19:47:03,196: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-04-26 19:47:08,194: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-04-26 19:47:11,471: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: OJ.tasks.judge_delay[12a1a1cb-6822-463c-b4a7-7aefc20b951c]
[2017-04-26 19:47:11,492: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <function _fast_trace_task at 0x7f87e6e28378> (args:('OJ.tasks.judge_delay', '12a1a1cb-6822-463c-b4a7-7aefc20b951c', (<Submit: 9912 A+B Problem testbot80 1 -1>,), {}, {'callbacks': None, 'delivery_info': {'routing_key': 'celery', 'redelivered': False, 'priority': 0, 'exchange': 'celery'}, 'retries': 0, 'id': '12a1a1cb-6822-463c-b4a7-7aefc20b951c', 'args': (<Submit: 9912 A+B Problem testbot80 1 -1>,), 'headers': {}, 'chord': None, 'reply_to': '02ac5b4b-c4b2-3020-aef0-7e930a64f174', 'is_eager': False, 'timelimit': (None, None), 'expires': None, 'hostname': 'celery@OJ', 'kwargs': {}, 'taskset': None, 'group': None, 'eta': None, 'errbacks': None, 'correlation_id': '12a1a1cb-6822-463c-b4a7-7aefc20b951c', 'task': 'OJ.tasks.judge_delay', 'utc': True}) kwargs:{})
[2017-04-26 19:47:11,499: DEBUG/MainProcess] Task accepted: OJ.tasks.judge_delay[12a1a1cb-6822-463c-b4a7-7aefc20b951c] pid:5559
[2017-04-26 19:47:13,197: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-04-26 19:47:18,198: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-04-26 19:47:23,195: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2017-04-26 19:47:28,197: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
^C
worker: Hitting Ctrl+C again will terminate all running tasks!

worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,308: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Closing Hub...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,308: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Closing Pool...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,309: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Closing Consumer...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,309: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Stopping Consumer...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,309: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Closing Connection...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,310: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Closing Events...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,310: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Closing Mingle...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,310: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Closing Tasks...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,310: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Closing Control...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,310: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Closing Gossip...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,311: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Closing Heart...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,311: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Closing event loop...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,311: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Stopping event loop...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,311: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Stopping Heart...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,312: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Stopping Gossip...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,317: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Stopping Control...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,319: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Stopping Tasks...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,320: DEBUG/MainProcess] Canceling task consumer...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,320: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Stopping Mingle...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,321: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Stopping Events...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,321: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Stopping Connection...
[2017-04-26 19:47:30,321: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Stopping Pool...
```

We can see that the task was received but not executed, the conf file and test script are as follow:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from djcelery import celery
from OJ.models import *
import OJ.judpong as judger
@celery.task
def judge_delay(sub):
    judger.judgePong(sub)
    print("judeged.")
```

So what does `pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]` mean? Is something wrong with my configure file??

Comment: any luck figuring out what `pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]` means?

Answer (score 7):

I'm getting this same message. I use celery in a docker environment, where I start up the producer, 2 workers and flower. The moment I stop flower, the logline: `pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]` disappears.

Comment: Is there any way to silence this specific log message, other than changing loglevel to higher than DEBUG?

Comment: It's a response to poller running in flower. if you shutdown flower, you don't have that log anymore. If you have to use flower, you have to look further inside celery to disable this logging.

Answer (score 0):

The logline `pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None` indicates that some service sent a `enable_events()` command to the worker. The most likely scenario is that Flower is responsible for this.
Flower, by default,  periodically sends Celery enable_events commands to all workers ([docs](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#enable-events)).
To prevent this, run Flower with this option set to False:

```
celery flower --enable_events=False
```

Also check the [events](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/cli.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-E) option for Celery to make the  worker send task-related events that can be captured by monitors.